# Python and tkinter: event handling inside class

Tags: python-3.x, events, tkinter

I want my program to do some code when any of the keys on the keyboard is pressed.

```
from tkinter import *

class MyProgram(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        super().__init__(self.root)
        self.bind_all('<Key>', key)
        return

    def key(self, event):
        if event.char == event.keysym or len(event.char) == 1:
            #do some code on event
            print("key pressed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp = MyProgram(Tk())
    mainloop()
```

This is my code but I get error that I'm missing an event parameter in key() fuction.

Comment: Where is the Thread supposed to get the event to deliver to your function?  Handling keys in a Tkinter program is done via the `.bind()` method on widgets, threads have nothing to do with it (and generally don't get along well with Tkinter anyway).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one line of code. `self.bind_all('<Key>', key)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use `self.`, and there is no function named `key` in `__init__` so Python gives you a NameError. The solution is simple; just add `self.` before `key` on line 7:

```
class MyProgram(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        super().__init__(self.root)
        self.bind_all('<Key>', self.key)
        return
```